# $dbhost=localhost $dbuser=root etc, on each php page, how to fix?

Tags: php

i have been given a php application as an internship project to clean up. The developer before has declared stuff like dbhost,dbuser so many times. On each script page.  I was wondering what sort of design php developers use to get around this.  i.e making a property file ? etc..

Answer (score 5):

Generally most applications have a common include file, usually named something like "bootstrap", that defines global options and values and sets up some initialisation code. Then each page that is requested includes this file first.

In your case you'd put your database configuration in this bootstrap (perhaps traditionally in `/includes/bootstrap.php`), then for each page where it is required `require "./includes/bootstrap.php";`.

As an example, [phpBB includes](https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb/blob/develop/web/index.php) its 'kernel bootstrapper' on each page.

Comment: I use this method for my projects. The 1 exception, if the DB connection isn't required on all pages I *sometimes* write a function with the DB connection information into the global file and then call the function only when required to connect to the DB, this isn't common and I'm not actually a fan of it but in some apps on an internal server it may be appropriate.

Comment: The file mentioned may not only consist of configuration data, but may also include the database setup and other setups/tests that are done during application startup (which is also my "bootstraps"-filename: startup.php)

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid errors you should use require_once:

> require_once "./includes/bootstrap.php";

This way even if multiple scripts try to include that specific file it is only included once.

Do not make a property file, or, if you insist, be certain that it cannot be downloaded through HTTP. The advantage of a PHP file is that, even if hackers guess the file name, it won't reveal much.

Answer (score 0):

Put all DB credentials into a separate .PHP file, e.g. db_settings.php and then insert everywhere

```
<?
 ...
include "db_settings.php"; 
... ?>
```

You may even insert database connection code into the same file.